# How can I make a slider out of my image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a photo gallery that looks like this:

[image: like this]

Whenever I add a photo, these cards get smaller and smaller, but I want to only show 4 photos at once and hide others, and make a some kind of slider. I tried changing container width and making overflow-x: scroll, but it doesn't seem to work. Could I achieve a slider effect with this gallery style? And how? I'm new to js, so I tried looking for a solution on other sites, but they are with static cards only, and I don't know how to implement that with my gallery.

```css
.containerss {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4% 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 86vh;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin: 0 2%;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.box>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover {
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}

.box:hover>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerss">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x807" loading=lazy>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x808" loading=lazy>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x810" loading=lazy>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x802" loading=lazy>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your gallery with an `100%` width wrapper with horizontal scroll, and then wide your gallery container as you like.

```css
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow: scroll-x;
}

.containerss {
    display: flex;
    width: 130%;
    padding: 4% 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 86vh;
}

.box {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin: 0 2%;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.box>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
}

.box:hover>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="containerss">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x807" loading=lazy>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x808" loading=lazy>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x810" loading=lazy>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x802" loading=lazy>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x802" loading=lazy>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but I would like to keep a margin on the right side. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps shrinking the `wrapper` will do?

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.